# Do Hindu scriptures allow adopting better moral teachings from other cultures and religions?

Tags: other-religions

Modern-day Hindus seem to follow a mixture of moral and philosophical teachings drawn from a variety of cultures and religions, both eastern and western. E.g., some Hindus actively choose a vegan diet considering it to be morally superior to a vegetarian diet.

Do Hindu scriptures allow adopting better morals from other cultures and religions?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Do take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: “some Hindus actively choose a vegan diet considering it to be morally superior to a vegetarian diet.” <—— It is not “morally superior” like as if there is some kinda race to be superior in morals. No. Not at all. It is for kindness & respect of everything. Vegan is most best for animals, the planet, for climate change, for health, all this stuffs 